# How to mock a command service to call private methods called by it?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I have a CommandController class with one responsibilty, provide to the CommandService the Module commands. To hide the implementation the class registers the commands and contain private methods with the implementation, something like this:

```
internal class CommandController
{
    private ICommandService commandService;

    public void RegisterCommands()
    {
        this.commandService.Register("ExampleCommand", this.ExecuteExampleCommand);
    }

    private void ExecuteExampleCommand()
    {
        ... implementation here ...
    }
}
```

How can I test the ExecuteExampleCommand in a unit test mocking the ICommandService so I don't test more than one class at a time (anyway it's likely that I won't have the service registered in a UT environment)?

I hope the question is clear enought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily access mock's method invocation arguments using `WhenCalled`. For example, if you want to execute action passed to `Register` you can do this:

```
registry.Stub(r => r.Register(
        Arg<String>.Is.Equal("ExampleCommand"),
        Arg<Action>.Is.Anything))
    .WhenCalled(invocation => ((Action) invocation.Arguments[1])());
```

When `RegisterCommands` is called, mock will execute your private method.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but i think that the method "ExecuteExampleCommand" should be extracted to a class, like "*ExampleCommandHandler*". Then, in the Register commands you would pass the command, and the *ExampleCommandHandler*, which could be mocked.

```
internal class CommandController
{
    private ICommandService commandService;

    public void RegisterCommands()
    {
        this.commandService.Register("ExampleCommand", this.ExampleCommandHandler);
    }

    private ExampleCommandHandler exampleCommandHandler;
}

internal class ExampleCommandHandler : ICommandHandler
{
    void Execute()
    {
    }
}
```

or just

```
this.commandService.Register("ExampleCommand", new ExampleCommandHandler())
```

Comment: Could be one solution but then the ExecuteExampleCommand would be public and available to others. As this is intended to be used by a large community of developers I'm trying to avoid they call the method directly and use the command.

Comment: Edited my post to show what i had in mind. Hard to say what you rly want without some more context. Basicly i think that registering commands, and executing them are separate things, and should be splitted in different classes.

Comment: I agree with the separation of concerns, but in this case I prefer to mix registration and execution to be more a blackbox. Internal does not help as the other developers are developing inside the same assembly (which is a big one).